# Blazor Server System.ObjectDisposedException issues when updating pages

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Added the process to update the data every second in Blazor Server.

This works fine, but when I press refresh page (F5) in my browser I get the following error:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot process pending renders after the renderer has been disposed.
ObjectDisposed_ObjectName_Name'
```

The target code is here

```
@code {
  private List<Models.Recipe> recipes { get; set; }
  private List<Models.NowOrder> nowOrders { get; set; }
  private List<Models.PlanOrder> planOrders { get; set; }
  System.Threading.Timer _timer;

  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
    using (var dbContext = DbFactory.CreateDbContext())
    {
        this.recipes = dbContext.Recipes.ToList();
        this.planOrders = dbContext.PlanOrders.ToList();
        this.nowOrders = dbContext.NowOrders.ToList();
    }

    _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(async (_) =>
    {
        Time = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        databaseValue = await TimerProcessGetValue();
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);    
    }, null, 0, 1000);
  }

  public void Dispose() 
  {
    _timer?.Dispose();
  }

  public async Task<int?> TimerProcessGetValue()
  {
      int? timerProcessValue;
      using (var dbContext = DbFactory.CreateDbContext())
      {
         timerProcessValue = (await dbContext.TestTable.SingleAsync(x => x.Id == 1)).TestValue;
      }
      return timerProcessValue;
  }
}
```

When refreshing the page "await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);"

If you comment out the following part, you will not get an error even if you press the F5 key, so I think that my handling of asynchronous processing is wrong, but I am troubled because I can not find the same case even if I search for the error I am.

What do you think is the cause of this?
Thank you for your cooperation.

```
_timer = new System.Threading.Timer(async (_) =>
{
    Time = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    databaseValue = await TimerProcessGetValue();
    await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);    
}, null, 0, 1000);
```

Change to verification code

```
        _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(async (_) =>
    {
        Time = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        //databaseValue = await TimerProcessGetValue();
        await Task.Delay(500); //Added verification code.
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);    
    }, null, 0, 1000);
  }
```

Append.(10/10/2021)

Version used: net core 5.0.7.

Browser used: Edge.

I'm not using any other browser.

My environment is limited and I can only use Edge ...

Below are the three codes we have verified.

①This is an example using Dispose (WaitHandle).

This did not improve the error.

```
public void Dispose()
{
    using(System.Threading.WaitHandle waitHandle = new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false))
    {
        if (_timer.Dispose(waitHandle))
        {
            const int millisecondsTimeout = 500;
            if (!waitHandle.WaitOne(millisecondsTimeout))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Dispose Test");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

②This is an example using System.Timers.Timer.

the reload using the F5 key was successful.

```
private int currentCount = 0;
private Timer timer2 = new(1000);

    protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    timer2.Elapsed += (sender, eventArgs) => OnTimerCallback();
    timer2.Start();
}

private void OnTimerCallback()
{
    _ = InvokeAsync(() =>
    {
        currentCount++;
        Time = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        databaseValue = TimerProcessGetValue().Result;
        StateHasChanged();
    });
}

public void Dispose() => timer2.Dispose();
```

③Added error handling.

Even with this method, I succeeded in reloading with the F5 key without any error.

```
    try
    {
        _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(async (_) =>
        {
            Time = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            databaseValue = await TimerProcessGetValue();
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        }, null, 0, 1000);
    }
    catch
    {
        // empty on purpose
    }
```

Comment: Are you using `@implements IDisposable` in the markup section?

Comment: Can you make a [mre] by replacing `databaseValue = await TimerProcessGetValue();` with `Task.Delay(500);` ?  Because I cannot reproduce this error.  Do this with a new plain project.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information.
Yes, I am using @implements IDisposable.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Added verification code.
I'm sorry if I didn't meet what I wanted to do.
However, by replacing it with this await Task.Delay (500) ;, the page reload can be performed normally.
Why is this ...

Comment: That means it is caused by TimerProcessGetValue() somehow.

Comment: Even if I uncommented await TimerProcessGetValue (); while leaving the verification code await Task.Delay (500) ;, I was able to reload normally with the F5 key.

There is nothing wrong with await TimerProcessGetValue (); itself, there may be some other factor.


What was your intention to think that you should try await Task.Delay (500) ;?
I couldn't try much for this error.
I would like to refer to your troubleshooting ideas.

Comment: Please add the asp.net version to your question and state which Browser. Did you try different Browsers?

Answer (score 3):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=net-5.0

> When a timer is no longer needed, use the Dispose method to free the resources held by the timer. Note that callbacks can occur after the Dispose() method overload has been called, because the timer queues callbacks for execution by thread pool threads. You can use the Dispose(WaitHandle) method overload to wait until all callbacks have completed.

This is why `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);` is being called after the component is disposed.

Comment: That looks like the solution, but I think that DisposeAsync() is a better fit here.

Comment: Sorry for being late.
Thank you for your wonderful answer.

I'm inexperienced and not completely understandable, but is it okay to realize that when Dispose is called, it calls StateHasChanged, which was used in the component before it was destroyed?

Sure, I didn't get an error every time I reloaded the page. (Although it was almost an error ...)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Brianparker's answer:

replace `@implements IDisposable` with `@implements IAsyncDisposable`

and then replace the Dispose() method with

```
public ValueTask DisposeAsync()
{
    return _timer?.DisposeAsync() ?? ValueTask.CompletedTask;
}
```

---

Update

> but I get the same error

I can't reproduce your error but I suppose that F5 is rather brutal.

You could try putting a try/catch aroud the StateHasChanged call:

```cs
try
{
  await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);    
}
catch
{  // empty on purpose
}
```

Comment: Sorry for being late.
Thank you very much for showing me the correction example.

It's a way of writing that I'm new to, so I'll try to find out what it means.

I will try to correct it immediately with the contents you received.

Comment: I tried the code that taught me, but I get the same error and the situation doesn't improve ...
I will check it a bit more….

Comment: Hmm, I cannot reproduce this. You are sure it happens with the TimerProcessGetValue line disabled?  I added a possible patch, give it a try.

Comment: I am always grateful for your help.
I don't have an environment to try it now due to circumstances, so I will try it tomorrow.
I tried Dispose (WaitHandle) today, as others have answered.
It is this link that I referred to. (I'm sorry it's not in English)[C # programming commentary](https://so-zou.jp/software/tech/programming/c-sharp/thread/).
But in conclusion, this also didn't improve the error.It's just a personal speculation, but I think it's also affected by being system.threading.timer, so I'll try it with System.Timers.Timer tomorrow.
I will tell you the result immediately.

Comment: Sorry for being so late.
I added the code I tried to the question.

First of all, Dispose (WaitHandle) did not resolve the error.
As I followed the code while debugging, it seemed that StateHasChanged was called after Dispose was called, as pointed out.

In the System.Timers.Timer example, the reload is successful.

As I told you at the end, I am adding error handling. (I'm sorry if the description method is wrong)
Again, reloading with the F5 key and regular processing are working properly.

A few
I tried it but I have no idea what caused it ...